# Selenium not able to open new Window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to open new window in selenium? I have used below code

```
driver.get("https://google.com");

Thread.sleep(1000);

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector)).sendKeys(Keys.ALT + "f4");
```

But still, this is not working.

Comment: But isn't alt+f4 for closing windows, not opening new ones...

Comment: Did you even google your query before asking the question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Use JavascriptExecutor to execute `window.open()`.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer this,

To Open new tab,  `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");`

To jump on tab with defined Index tab,

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```